# My animations are slower/buggy in IE and Edge

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-animations, microsoft-edge, box-shadow

I have a few animations but I noticed that in IE and Edge my animations are slower and also one of the animations is not visible at all. It is just fine in chrome and Firefox. The box shadow is the one that is not visible at all. Any ideas why its not visible and why it is slower (looks like it is not as smooth)?

```
@keyframes fadeInAndOut {
17% {
    opacity: 1;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 23px #fff;
}

25% {
    opacity: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 31px 23px #fff;
}

92% {
    opacity: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Smoothness:
   with CSS animations/transitions you should always animate props that do not affect layout: `transform` and `opacity`. You **could** animate other things like margins and so but thread that does the job of CSS animations/transitions is not good with props that require layout recalculation. So, for box-shadow and anything other then transform and opacity use JavaScript animations.
2. Non-working animations:
   Incorrect keyframe rule - animatable values in keyframes declaration should always be numeric (not things like `none`).